# redircet stdout to file using variable python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to redirect o/p of shell commands to file using variable "path" but it is not working

```
import os, socket, shutil, subprocess
host = os.popen("hostname -s").read().strip()
path = "/root/" + host

if os.path.exists(path):
  print(path, "Already exists")
else:
   os.mkdir("Directory", path , "Created")

os.system("uname -a" > path/'uname')  # I want to redirect o/p of shell commands to file using varibale "path" but it is not working 
os.system("df -hP"> path/'df')
```

Comment: Use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean exactly? Are you getting an error?

Comment: subprocess.run("uname -a", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
Out[199]: CompletedProcess(args='uname -a', returncode=0, stdout=b'Linux abhithak 4.13.0-38-generic #43~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 17:48:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux\n')
which option to use to save in file using variable ?

Comment: /root/abhithak Already exists
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-202-dead83ea1f54> in <module>()
      9
     10
---> 11 os.system("uname -a" > path/'uname')  # I want to redirect o/p of shell commands to file using varibale "path" but it is not working
     12 os.system("df -hP"> path/'df')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Please **read** the error it is giving you: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'`. The error is with the `/` operator. It tells you this. Look back until you find it. You see `path/'df'`. They are both `'str'`s. You cannot divide strings. It is telling you what's wrong: that you have written something incorrect and not what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the bare > and / symbols in the os.system command...

Here is a python2.7 example with os.system that does what you want

```
import os
path="./test_dir"
command_str="uname -a > {}/uname".format(path)
os.system(command_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *very* minimal example using [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run). Also, search StackOverflow for "python shell redirect", and you'll get this result right away:

[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python/92395#92395)

```
import subprocess


def run(filename, command):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as stdout_file:
        process = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        stdout_file.write(process.stdout)
        return process.returncode

run('test_out.txt', 'ls')
```

Comment: if we use varibale in run it won't work . I want to save in path like host = os.popen("hostname -s").read().strip()
     ...: path = "/root/" + host

Comment: In [223]:  run(path/'uname', 'uname -a')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-223-1cf1c321c5dd> in <module>()
----> 1 run(path/'uname', 'uname -a')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Just modify my code to do what you want. Write another version of my `run` method to return the hostname rather than write it to a file.